# How should "Merry Christmas" and "Happy New Year" be capitalized?

Tags: capitalization, christmas

How should "Merry Christmas" and "Happy New Year" be capitalized?

Here are some examples taken from some of the top results on Google:

> I’d like to be among the first to wish you a very Merry Christmas.
>
> Share the spirit of peace and joy on this occasion of Merry Christmas with your acquaintances and loved ones.
>
> Just wanted to wish you all a Merry Christmas, Happy Holidays, or a Happy whatever you are celebrating at this time of year.

And here is what [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Merry_Christmas_and_a_Happy_New_Year!) says:

> Merry Christmas and a Happy New Year!

Is this capitalization correct? If so, does this mean that "Merry Christmas" and "Happy New Year" are proper nouns?

Comment: "Christmas" and "New Year" are proper nouns; the "Merry" and "Happy" are modifiers capitalized due to association.

Comment: The adverb "Very" is modifying the capitalized adjective "Merry", so I'd capitalize "Very" here.

Comment: Capitalizing Every Damn Word has even spread to Hungarian, which traditionally *doesn't* capitalize much at all. So it ought to be *Kellemes karácsonyi ünnepeket*, since the -i makes *Karácsony* (Christmas) into an adjective, and there's no reason to capitalize *ünnep* (holiday). Naturally, if the greeting is in the middle of a sentence, the first K should be lowercase as well. But nowadays, all the Hungarian websites, cards, and stores have the phrase in full Title Caps, and it bugs the heck out of me. (And my mother - I come by my pedantry honestly.)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As others have mentioned, Christmas and New Year are proper nouns, and thus are capitalized. Generally the phrases "Merry Christmas" and "Happy New Year" are used in greetings, as headings, or in some other isolated way, and thus "Happy" and "Merry" are the first word of the sentence, and thus those words are capitalized.

> Happy New Year!

is a sentence by itself, and thus Happy should be capitalized.  It would not be necessary to capitalize "birthday" if you were saying "Happy birthday" instead of "Happy New Year".

> I wish you a merry Christmas and happy New Year.

is how I'd capitalize the words if they weren't being used on their own, but rather in a longer sentence.

Comment: I think that in most communications, including both informal and formal registers, "I wish you a Merry Christmas and a Happy New Year" (all caps) would also be accepted by most people without noticing any problem.  Perhaps in both cases (all-caps and not-all-caps), a minority would "notice an error" based on what they think is correct.

Comment: I assume the same goes for _happy Easter_? :)

Answer (score 3):

Christmas and New Year are proper nouns.

I *know* that Merry Christmas and other such greetings are usually capitalised, but the reason why is unclear.

They are not proper nouns, but they are phrases and as such the first letter of the first word is often capitalised, but this is not set in stone. I get the impression that their are cultural differences, that people state-side are more likely not to capitalise Merry and Happy, but I can't confirm this.

You could also perhaps consider them quotes that have lost the quotation marks:

> We wish you a 'Merry Christmas'

However, there is a school of thought that goes against this; they consider merry Christmas perfectly acceptable, though to me is looks rather odd.