# Capitalization for email greeting: Good morning OR Good Morning

Tags: capitalization, letter-writing, salutations

In an email greeting "Good morning" does the word "morning" need to be capitalized?  Is it Good Morning or Good morning?

Comment: It's just Good morning, lowercase m.

Comment: @RK01 Why capitalise the g in good? My default use would be *good morning*, unless there were an overriding reason to capitalise the g - like it was the start of a sentence, or the opening word of a speech quotation.

Comment: @WS2 It is a greeting, so it is capitalized.

Comment: @RK01 And as such always appears between quotation marks? I'm trying hard to think of how it might be used other than that way.

Comment: Answered at [How should "Merry Christmas" and "Happy New Year" be capitalized?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6831/how-should-merry-christmas-and-happy-new-year-be-capitalized)

Answer (score 2):

Good Morning would appropriate if it where a title or together as one for something but in a general greeting, the lowercase is m is just fine.

Answer (score 2):

**1.** If you search Google images for "good morning" you will discover that the following occur on greetings cards:

Good Morning!

good morning!

GOOD MORNING!

However I did not see an example of "Good morning" on a greetings card.

**2.** If you are writing dialog, only the first word should be capitalised, e.g.

"Good morning!" said John.

"Good morning, John!" I replied.

**3.** If it is the first line of an email, my choice would be, e.g.

*Good morning!
  Thanks for those photos you sent me ...*

but I don't think it would be incorrect to say:

*Good Morning!
  Thanks for those photos you sent me ...*

I would say that it is a matter of style.