# Grammar of "A happy New Year 2019"

Tags: grammaticality

Consider this sentence: "I wish you a merry Christmas and a happy New Year 2019."

Is this correct gramatically? The "2019" feels a bit tacked on to me, but I need to mention it in some way in this particular scenario.

Comment: It's not something anybody would normally say. The closest equivalent would be *I wish you a Merry Christmas and all the best in 2019.* Adding something after *New Year* is very strange.

Comment: It is grammatically unobjectionable.  Grammaticality deals in sentence structure, parts of speech. Pragmatics deals in idiomaticity. And I'd say it's fine there too, but as you say, not as common and a bit more awkward than without the 2019. I think that may arise from a certain, I don't know, prolix character. In this context, 2019 is already implied and everyone knows it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As people have already said in the comments, the construction you have is a bit unusual. It is found on rare occasions (see below), but if you wish to be sure that no one will think your construction strange, your best bet is to rephrase.

Some possibilities:

*I wish you a merry Christmas and all the best in 2019.* (Jason's suggestion)
*I wish you a merry Christmas and a happy 2019!* (see [here](https://www.businesswritingblog.com/business_writing/2006/12/on_to_new_years.html))
*As 2019 approaches, I wish you a merry Christmas and a happy New Year!*

<sub>On whether *merry* and *happy* should be capitalized, see e.g. [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6831/how-should-merry-christmas-and-happy-new-year-be-capitalized) (conclusion: probably both capitalized and non-capitalized versions are OK, as long as both *merry* and *happy* are treated equaly).</sub>

**Examples of usage of *happy New Year 20xx***

Here are examples of such usage (e.g. *Happy New Year 2001!*) from published literature: [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=rIfu52G5sngC&lpg=PA101&dq=%22happy%20new%20year%2C%202000%22&pg=PA101#v=onepage&q=%22happy%20new%20year,%202000%22&f=false), [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=lgWNBAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA460&dq=%22happy%20new%20year%202001%22&pg=PA460#v=onepage&q=%22happy%20new%20year%202001%22&f=false), [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=kSkEAQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA41&dq=%22happy%20new%20year%202005%22&pg=PA41#v=onepage&q=%22happy%20new%20year%202005%22&f=false), and [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=LWcsAQAAMAAJ&q=%22happy+new+year+2008%22&dq=%22happy+new+year+2008%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj774eQlfLeAhWmTt8KHfGyBaYQ6AEIOjAD).

One source has *happy New Year **of** 2018,* [here](https://collegiatewaterpolo.org/happy-new-year-collegiate-water-polo-association-2/).